# JSON Encode To PHP Variable via Curl fails with empty response

Tags: php, json, curl, urlencode

i have searched a lot on google and here but im not getting any further with my problem. I am not a coder though I am trying to parse JSON to PHP Variables, but i get an empty response, where i want a table to be shown or at least any jsondata

Here is what my code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Available Agents </h1>

<?php
$url = 'https://url/livewebservice/imoscontactagentstate?Username=username&Pwd=password&Cmd=GetState&ResultType=JSON';
//  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init ($url);
$data = json_encode ($data,true);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
' Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded ',
'charset=utf-8')
);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
return $result;
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
 print_r($result); 
foreach ($result as $key => $value)
              {
          echo '  <td><font  face="calibri"color="red">'.$value[type].'   </font></td><td><font  face="calibri"color="blue">'.$value[category].'   </font></td><td><font  face="calibri"color="green">'.$value[amount].'   </font></tr><tr>';

           }
           echo "</tr></table>";

?>



</body>
</html>
```

I am grateful for any hints

Comment: Having a return in the middle won't help

Comment: collecting curl resp 1st than update your content? or better get from ajax?

Comment: if i put curl_close($ch); and return $result; after the foreach, i get a null response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved my Username did not have the permission to access the data and we made minor changes to the code so it looks like this:

```html
php


$data = array(

"UserName" => "Username",

"Pwd" => "Password",

"Cmd" => "GetAgentStateList",

"ResultType" => "JSON",

);

$url='https://host/livewebservice/service/?'.http_build_query($data);

 echo $url;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "charset=UTF-8",)); 

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)){

    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));

}

curl_close($ch);

$f_result=json_decode($result);

print_r($f_result);

?>
```

i hope this helps someone coming from google someday.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `true` from `$data = json_encode ($data,true);` as far as can i remember `true` is used only in json_decode to create an associative array

Comment: I think the `true` will be interpreted as the `JSON_HEX_TAG` option constant. I don't think it should matter much here, but you're right, a boolean isn't supposed to be there.

Comment: yes its wrong here but the result stays the same. i read about a wrong php version might be the cause but i'm not sure